# Prevent Sharepoint from Displaying Documents under People Search

Tags: search-results, people-search

We just found a major issue with the staff directory.  If you go under anyone’s name and hover over where it says “by Bob Doe” under their picture it shows a lot of information.  It is showing purchase authorizations, reimbursement forms, and also it is showing 30 day reviews for Genomics.  Not sure what else this might be showing but people shouldn’t be seeing this.

I am not sure if you know how to STOP this from showing but this has to be fixed ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would do is check to see if you can find those items on the content search side.  Do a regular search for content with that same name.  That author mini-search by contact feature uses the search system as well which should mean that search is not configured properly.  When properly configured all search results are security trimmed, including that mini-search within the profile information.  If security trimming is not taking place, then you want to verify that the content access account IS NOT an administrator account but just a regular domain account.

Here are the instructions for changing the Default Content Access Account:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261796.aspx

If you have to change this account, which I suspect you do, then you will want to reset the index and initiate a full crawl afterwards to rebuild the index with the correct Access Control List (ACL) information so that security trimming will work.